# Which platform to use for fastest neo4j graph traversal?

Tags: java, python, performance, neo4j

I have to do traversals on neo4j graph in real time. The graph contains around 200,000 nodes and 300,000 relationships. My main concern is that results should be super fast.

Should I write the traversal algorithms in Java? Does Using python (py2neo or bulbflow) for the same has significant performance issues? My personal preference is for python here if performance is same for both python and java.

Comment: Super fast is too vague to mean anything.

Comment: What I meant was which platform will give me the results in least time, as I have clearly put in the title!

Comment: Least time is also totally vague, you should instead specify how fast you need things to be. For instance, if there were a solution that would take only 98% of the time of the standard solution, but was 10k lines of code instead of 10, and the standard solution ran in 2ms anyway, you wouldn't want that solution. Similarly if the fastest solution takes 3s to return it's not very useful.

Comment: Indeed, I bet we could write a nice 10k-line C program to read the neo4j store and traverse slightly faster than the Java API. :P

Comment: I finally used cypher queries. For my case they were much faster than traversal algorithms

Answer (score 5):

In general, the fastest way to do traversals in neo4j is with the Java API.

You might consider testing to see if it is fast enough before potentially prematurely optimizing. Try one of the python libraries w/ Cypher to see how it performs.

If you do have to resort to the Java API, you can usually get away with writing a simple unmanaged extension (<50 lines of java/scala), and then call that from your python.